# Jquery-ui selectable problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a problem regarding jquery selectable , I have div that contains user information , this is my div

```
<div class="user-container" id="append_users">
     <div class="fc-event draggable-user" ondblclick="sys.callUserProfile('+user.id+')" id="user_'+user.id+'"style="z-index: 9999;"  onmousedown="sys.mouseDown()" onmouseup="sys.mouseLeave()">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <input type="hidden" value="'+user.id+'" id="user_'+ user.id + '_value" class="userId">
             <div class="row">
             <div class="col-xs-3 avatar-col">
               <img src="'+getUserImage(user.avatar)+'"width="100%">
             </div>
             <div class="col-xs-9 data-col">
               <p class="fullName dataText" >'+user.fullName+'</p>
                <p class="usr_Gender dataText" >Male</p>
                 <div style="position: relative"><li class="availableUnavailable"></li><li class="usr_profesion dataText" >AVAILABLE</li></div>
                  <p class="user_id" style="float:right;margin:3px">'+user.employee_id+'</p>
                 </div>
             </div>
           </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

and I need the whole fc-event div to function as one , so the div with id="append_users" should contain the selectable class and the div with class fc-event should be considered as selection , I tried like this

```
( "#append_users" ).selectable();
```

but all childs take the `ui-selectee` class and it doesn't function at all, so what I want to do is the div with class fc-event should be considered as one, I hope i am clear, anyone please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation doesn't make it hugely clear, but from looking at the code and descriptions of the demos on the jQueryUI website (http://jqueryui.com/selectable/) it can be seen that the element you execute the "selectable" command against is intended to the *container* for the things you want to be selectable. It will automatically make all the child elements of that element into things which can be selectable. This is logical because generally you'd want to have several selectable items in a list and be able choose one or more items to select.

So if you want your "append_users" element to be selectable, you have to make the parent of that element the target of your "selectable" command. You haven't shown what the parent is, so for the purpose of example I'm going to assume it's just another `<div>`:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="selectable">
  <div class="user-container" id="append_users">
    <div class="fc-event draggable-user"  id="user_1" style="z-index: 9999;">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <input type="hidden" value="1" id="user_1_value" class="userId">
         <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-3 avatar-col">

           <img src="https://i.imgur.com/db4KgSp.png" width="100px">
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-9 data-col">
           <p class="fullName dataText" >user.fullName</p>
            <p class="usr_Gender dataText" >Male</p>
             <div style="position: relative"><li class="availableUnavailable"></li><li class="usr_profesion dataText" >AVAILABLE</li></div>
              <p class="user_id" style="float:right;margin:3px">user.employee_id</p>
             </div>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$("#selectable").selectable();
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/s6Lmy70b/2/ for a working demonstration.

(N.B. This is using very slightly adjusted markup compared to yours, just for demonstration and to make it easier to get it working, but the principle is the same regardless of the exact content being displayed)

Comment: i this case works fine, the #append_user is the main div, and the fc event is the user div that should be selected, in my case when I add the selectable to the main div and when i try to select the specific user it doesn't add the ui-selected class, they all have ui-selectee but when i select i doesn't add the ui-selected class

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. Here it is working perfectly - the "fc-event" element gets the ui-selected class added when you click on it. http://jsfiddle.net/s6Lmy70b/3/ . If it's still not working for you in your own code, then perhaps something else is interfering. Could it be related to the other javascript events which are placed on that element? Do they work? What tasks to they do? Do you have any console errors occurring when you click on the event?

Comment: I have drag and drop events on that element, maybe that is the problem , I did like you did but it still doesn't add the class ui-selected

Comment: If you answer the questions in my last comment I might be able to help you. Speculation about drag-and-drop events etc isn't helpful and doesn't enable me to understand what's wrong. I need cold, hard facts and/or code. I need enough information to reproduce the problem (as we've also discussed on the other question I was trying to help you with)

Comment: you are very kind person, thanks for your help but really there is no much to say , I don't have code that prevents it from functioning, either I am doing it wrong or either there should be a different solution for my case, I just see on the console that only ui-selected class is not added , all other are there, ui-selectable is added , ui-selectee is added but ui-selected isn't, I stop all other functions I only let this one it still doesn't work

Comment: " I don't have code that prevents it from functioning" . If it's not working properly then probably you do have something interfering. There must be a reason for it. Your fc-event element has `onmousedown="sys.mouseDown()" onmouseup="sys.mouseLeave()"` events on it for instance. What do these functions do? Do they work properly? Does a console error happen when clicking on the fc-event element? If so it might prevent the jqueryUI code from executing. There must be _something_ different about what you're doing compared to me. Can you edit your question to show your current code?

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/s6Lmy70b/4/ - setting draggable on the fc-event stops the selectable from working. No errors, just nothing happens, as you mention. So probably these two things are just incompatible. Perhaps you need to re-think your design a bit.

Comment: can it be the jquery version? i have /*! jQuery v1.12.4 | (c) jQuery Foundation | jquery.org/license */

Comment: Well my demo uses the latest jquery, so I doubt it. But I just told you, it's the draggable conflicting with the selectable.

Comment: yes i see, so that is the problem? any solution how to work with this

Comment: You simply can't put both things on the same element. You have to find another way to implement your requirement. Since I don't know what the actual overall requirement is, beyond "make something selectable", I can't suggest much. You'll have to rethink your page design a bit, I guess.